# How to create a concrete surface texture to use as background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, background, texture, mockup

I am trying to achieve this noisy background **behind** the cards. How can I recreate this effect?

[image]

Comment: Why are business cards _always_ levitating in these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a simple tileable texture that you can expand or contract as needed. It's easy to repurpose that way and doesn't eat much disk space.

Try [SubtlePatterns.com](http://SubtlePatterns.com). Atle Mo creates and curates a very nice set of patterns there, some of which would work perfectly for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Take a photograph of a concrete slab or purchase a photograph of concrete from any number of stock photography sites.

There's no reason to spend time and effort to recreate something if a simple photo will work. Often the photo works better anyway.

Comment: agreed: take a myPhone to Home Despot* or similar home improvement store and snap some closeups of their countertops. (*any similarity to actual products and services is coincidental)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a concrete or recycled paper texture. The best option is probably to use a Photoshop brush over a light gray background layer.

Some ideas:

- [Hard concrete Photoshop brushes](http://www.brusheezy.com/brushes/2201-15-hard-concrete-texture-brushes)
- [Concrete textures](http://flyerheroes.com/10-free-concrete-textures/)
- [Paper textures](http://naldzgraphics.net/freebies/200-high-quality-free-paper-textures-to-grab/)